Rails 6.1 Multiple Databases with Active Record
I have upgraded my Rails application from version 5 to 6.1. Previously, I used the distribute_reads gem to connect to the replica database from the code. With Rails 6.1's native support for multiple databases, I am removing the distribute_reads gem and transitioning to the built-in functionality for connecting to replicas. I am following the Rails documentation for this process, but I'm encountering some issues in my local environment.
I have following changes in my database.yml file
default: &default
 adapter: postgis
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: true
 username: username
 password: password
 host: 127.0.0.1
 pool: 10
 port: 5432

development:
 primary:
   <<: *default
   database: db1

 replica:
   <<: *default
   database: db1_clone
   replica: true  

initially I want manually connection switch so I can replace all the old distribute_read blocks with ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) block but when I am trying that I am getting error
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :reading) do
 User.count
end

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found for the 'reading' role.)
I have tried many ways to resolve but unable to resolve so looking for some help
